# trazer código html do banco

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Tenho a seguinte dúvida, sei que não estou fazendo do jeito mais certo, mas acredito que me servirá. estou tentando integrar meu projeto da Faculdade com o Pagseguro, porém estou achando complexo em relação a utilização da API, porém vi que no Pagseguro temos a possibilidade de utilizar botões gerados pelo site, e estes são em HTML. Meu sistema tem o produto que tem diversos valores, e neste caso para cada produto teria que ser gerado um botão, pois no Pagseguro para gerar o botão preciso obrigatoriamente inserir o nome do produto e valor para então ser gerado um código para este botão. então para cada valor, geraria um botão, e então este código seria armazenado no banco de dados, e quando o Index exibisse os produtos, queria pegar este código HTML do banco e exibir na tela, porém em sua função de botão, mas até o momento, consgui exibir apenas o HTML

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

o correto seria assim

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

na view, estou usando

```
<i>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Botao)</i>
```

Comment: Reverti sua edição, pois você está mudando os pontos essenciais de uma pergunta que já foi respondida, e marcada como aceita. Se tem nova dúvida, o correto é fazer uma pergunta em separado. Se for apenas um pequeno ajuste, pode deixar um comentário na resposta do @Ricardo pedindo ajuda ou um complemento, evitando a necessidade de nova pergunta.

Comment: PS: se vc e o @Ricardo entenderem de comum acordo que a modificação não invalida a resposta dada, basta usar o histórico em http://pt.stackoverflow.com/posts/161900/revisions para recuperar os dados alterados, sem prejuizo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Se o código que vem do banco é igual ao que você postou na primeira imagem, você precisa fazer o decode e usar `Html.Raw` do `Razor`, assim:

```
<i>    
   @Html.Raw(HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(Model.Botao));
</i>
```

Eu costumo sempre jogar o conteúdo dentro de um elemento `div`, o que ajuda na formatação.

Comment: funcionou parte, mas ele exibiu esta mensagem **System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper`1[System.Collectio** acima do botão. vou mostrar a imagem

Comment: O seu `html` contém uma tag `form`, existe alguma outra tag `form` na sua página, ou `Html.BeginForm()` ?

Comment: inseri o código fonte na resposta...

Comment: Já localizei o erro, tinha um @html perdido ali a cima do botão, enquanto estava editando o código apaguei um conteúdo sem notar, e agora está tudo normal. Obrigado